# OnTextChanged not working when used with AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox as per below:

```
Search:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearchCompany" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtSearchCompany_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

I also have an `AutoCompleteExtender` linked with the textbox as per below:

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="2"
            CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
            TargetControlID="txtSearchCompany"
            ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
           CompletionListElementID="autocompleteDropDownPanel"
            >
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

When I choose something from the `AutoComplete` List, it does not fire the `onTextChanged` event. However, if I type something in the textbox and I don't select a value from the `AutoComplete` list, it then fires the `onTextChanged`.

Can someone please tell me what this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: show `SearchCustomers` method

Comment: Try removing the aspx textbox & put a html textbox & execute via jquery. Later on u can extend it as per ur requirements, Please  check this [URL](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know about the autocomplete logic and the Textbox control, they both wont work together as you are expecting because the OnTextChanged event only fires when something is also typed/changed in the textbox. Inspite of selecting a different value from autocomplete dropdown, this event wont work.

There is this link,not exact, but which also points in the same direction.
[Check this.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873198)

There may be some workarounds for this through which you can fire an event when a value is selected from dropdown list.

You can try writing an ajax event in a JavaScript/jQuery which would fire up an event on the server for the same and you can thereafter, perform the logic on the server and return the data as response through script.

Consider this as an example :

[Event Change with Jquery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)

This is the sample code :

```
function autocomplete() {
  $('.control').autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
         // ajax code to perform textChange logic
      },
      minLength: 1,
      change: function (event, ui) { SaveData(); }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes after switching to JQuery's autocomplete, I am not able to trigger an event on select. Seems to work much better that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnClientItemSelected** event from Client Script to fire TextChanged event

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
        CompletionInterval="100" 
        EnableCaching="false" 
        CompletionSetCount="10" 
        TargetControlID="txtSearchCompany"
        ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
        CompletionListElementID="autocompleteDropDownPanel"
        OnClientItemSelected="DoTextChangedPostBack" >
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function DoTextChangedPostBack(source, eventArgs) {
       var hfield = $get('<%=txtSearchCompany.ClientID%>');
       hfield.value = eventArgs.get_value();
       __doPostBack("<%=txtSearchCompany.ID%>", "TextChanged");
    }
</script>
```